# Como criar aplicativo Android que utiliza softwares nativos do celular, como câmera, galeria, etc

Tags: java, android

Como eu faço para utilizar os recursos do celular ?
Por exemplo:
Eu crio um app, que quando o usuario clicar em "Tal" botao, abrir a camera do celular... ou a galeria... ou despertador.
Queria aprender isso, mas nao sei nem o que pesquisar.

Comment: O que você já tentou?

Comment: Nada... mas queria conhecer esses recursos. Exemplo, eu nao sei nem o que pesquiser, ou como pesquisar pra aprender entende ? Queria que me dessem apenas um norte aqui para começar.

Comment: Pesquise primeiro como criar um app android, você pode ver a documentação também, [neste link em inglês](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/develop/index.html) mas de fácil entendimento. Antes de aprender recursos, você deve aprender a mexer na ferramenta, conhecer a linguagem, seu funcionamento em si, neste link você tem tudo isso e muito mais. No mais, [tutoriais no google](https://goo.gl/b70pvx) tem bastante para começar e para tirar dúvidas ao se aventurar em criar um app, o SOpt sempre estará a disposição :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que você quer é resolvido usando o `Intent`

Uma `Intent` é uma descrição abstrata de uma operação a ser executada. Pode ser usada com [`startActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#startActivity(android.content.Intent)) para lançar um [`Activity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), o [`broadcastIntent`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#sendBroadcast(android.content.Intent)) para enviar para qualquer componente [`BroadcastReceiver`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) e `startService(Intent)` ou [`bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#bindService(android.content.Intent,%20android.content.ServiceConnection,%20int)) para comunicar com o serviço ([`Service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html)) no `background`.

Segue a documentação: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Antes de mais nada recomendo que estude Android e Java primeiro, segue um bom link pra isto:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tags/android/info

Segue alguns exemplos do uso do `Intent` pra estudo (não testei, faz um tempo que não trabalho com Android):

Abre a calculadora:

```
// activity name and package for stock calculator
private static final String CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME = "com.android.calculator2";
private static final String CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME = "com.android.calculator2.Calculator";

public void launchCalculator() {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
     intent.setComponent(new Component Name(CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME,
             CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME));
     try {
         this.start Activity(intent);
     } catch (ActivityNotFoundException noSuchActivity) {
         // handle exception where calculator intent filter is not registered
     }
 }
```

Seleciona um áudio:

```
public void launchMusicPlayer(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    intent.setDataAndType(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            AUDIO_MIME_TYPE);
    startActivityForResult(intent, FIND_SONG_INTENT);
}
```

Editor de texto:

```
public void launchTextEditor() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/somefile.txt");
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/plain");
        start Activity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No editor on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
     }
 }
```

Visualizar PDF:

```
public void launchPDFViewer() {
    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/Download/somefile.pdf");
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
        start Activity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "No viewer on this device",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
         toast.show();
     }
 }
```

<sub>Fonte: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/android-intents-for-app-integration-call-a-calculator-play-video-open-an-editor/</sub>

Comment: Pela resposta dele nos comentarios, aparentemente ele nem sabe como programar em java para android, ou se sabe, não ficou muito claro pela pergunta e nem pela resposta nos comentarios.

Comment: @DiegoFelipe Obrigado, resposta editada.

Comment: Cara, MUITO obrigado, era exatamente isso que eu queria... Otima explicação!